# Android Studio : Using ImageButton in different activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities : MainActivity and DetailActivity. An ImageButton is defined in activity_main.xml.

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/searchView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/pic" />
```

I want to use this ImageButton in DetailActivity.java. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You just add the button to the activity's `xml`. Say the MainActivity inflates `activity_main.xml`, the DetailsActivity should have its own layout e.g `activity_details.xml`. Copy the button code there and you should be able to use it.

Comment: That does not solve the problem. It just adds a new ImageButton to activity_detail layout which is undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two visible activities at once, and consequently can't modify views of one activity from another.

The standard way to influence parent activity state from child activity is to launch second activity with [`startActivityForResultMethod`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) (call it from `MainActivity` to launch `DetailActivity`) and observe for result in [`onActivityResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) method (you should override it in `MainActivity`).
In `DetailActivity` you should pass some result to `MainActivity` by calling [`setResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult(int,%20android.content.Intent)) method with `Intent` with some extras as second argument just before calling `finish`.